# NAs in y in Statistical Analysis

Tags: r, statistics

I have a problem with the following code below:

```
return1 = diff(log(bist))
return1[,1] <- na.locf(return1[,1],na.rm = F)
```

When I run the Dickey–Fuller test, I get the following error:

```
df.test <- ur.df(return1, type =c("drift"),lags = 0 )
```

> Error in ur.df(return1, type = c("drift"), lags = 0) : 
>   NAs in y.

Do you know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because of your data and the distribution of `NA`s due to the `log. If the first elements in`return1`are missing then they will not be filled in with`na.locf`.

If you change the first part of the code to

```
return1=diff(log(bist))
return1[,1]<-na.locf(return1[,1],na.rm = TRUE)
```

then you will have removed the first missing elements. Not sure how that matches with the `ur.df` test, though.